# MySQL SUM Query

Tags: sql, mysql

I've got two tables.

I'm trying to calculating the SUM quantity of tbl1

tbl1.xid is the primary, while tbl2.xid is the foreign

tbl1

```
xid pub quantity
1    1    10          
2    1    2      
3    0    1      
4    1    5
```

tbl2

```
id ttype fno xid qnty
1  A       0    1    0
2  A       1    1    3
3  B       1    1    4
4  A       1    2    1 
5  A       1    3    2
6  A       1    4    3
7  A       1    4    1
8  A       0    1    0
```

We are calculating the sum of tbl1's quantity

1) Whos tbl1.pub is 1
Thus tbl1.xid 3 is removed form the list, for it's pub is 0

Results

tbl1

```
xid pub quantity
1    1    10          
2    1    2      
4    1    5
```

2) AND Who's tbl1 has at least one tbl2.xid who's tbl2.ttype is 'A' and who's tbl2.fno is '0'
Thus tbl1.xid 2 & 4 are removed form the list, because none of them have at least one tbl2.xid who's fno is '0' and who's tbl2.ttype is 'A'

Results

parent_tbl1

```
xid pub quantity
1    1    10
```

The final results should be 10

Comment: So, I've been playing with this and 

`SELECT DISTINCT (
SUM( quantity )
) AS qnts
FROM tbl1
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl1.xid = tbl2.xid
WHERE pub =1
AND ttype =  'A'
AND fno =0
GROUP BY tbl2.id`

gets me down to 10, but if I add another xid (book?) to tbl1 that has a qualifying record in tbl2, I get a table, with two records that actually add up to the total we're looking for.

This is as far as I have time to get to right now, but this puzzle intrigues me, so I hope to continue on it later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(quantity) AS Total
FROM   tbl1
WHERE  pub=1
AND    EXISTS
       (SELECT *
       FROM    tbl2
       WHERE   tbl2.ttype = 'A'
       AND     tbl2.fno   = 0
       AND     tbl1.xid   = tbl2.xid
       )
```